# how to import a resource file to static code filed in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, properties, static

In my maven project, I have a static code filed like this:

```
static {
    int address = xxx;
    int port = xxx;
}
```

I want to use a property file to define the variable in that, the property file is in the resources directory in my project，but I've tried a lot of ways to import this property file to the static code filed, such as:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(RedisPool.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not using the properties in your code...write a class and of course you should use `getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`...if your `config.properties` files is located in `src/main/resources`...

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two alternatives you may use.

1. [templating-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)
2. [maven-replacer-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/)

Examles how to use are available on the website.